# Is there any difference between "differ widely" and "differ dramatically"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

The phrases "differ widely" and "differ dramatically" are both translated to "very different" or "have great difference" in my learner's dictionary.

It seems that "differ widely" means differences in many places.
I guess "differ dramatically" means totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes.  It's much the same as the difference between something that is *wide* and something that is *dramatic*:  One is a measure of *span*, and the other is a measure of *intensity*.

> The candidate has a **wide** lead in the polls (the lead is a significant number)
>
> The candidate has a **dramatic** lead in the polls (the lead is significant enough to instill a sense of excitement, surprise, and/or some other strong emotion)

In many contexts the two can be (and often are) interchangeable, but each does convey a different message.